# Android crash on check Preferences

Tags: android, crash

Can someone help me find the problem?
I have MainActivity, that when I go to stop mode of activity, it crashes.
In code of MainActivity.setPref(), that contains:

```
public void setPref(Context context){
   boolean CheckboxPreference3=false;
   boolean CheckboxPreference6=true;
   boolean CheckboxPreference9=true;
   boolean CheckboxPreference91=true;
   boolean CheckboxPreference10=true;
   boolean CheckboxPreference11=true;

   String IntPreference10="0";
   String CheckboxPreference4 = "";
   boolean CheckboxPreference5=false;

     SharedPreferences prefs2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference3 = prefs2.getBoolean("english", true);
     if (CheckboxPreference3){
         VarsN.english=true;
     }else{
         VarsN.english=false;
     }  

     SharedPreferences prefs5 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     boolean bool=true;
     if (VarsN.Titl1.contains("lite")){
         bool=false;
     }
     CheckboxPreference6 = prefs5.getBoolean("dynamic", bool);

     if (CheckboxPreference6){
         Vars.Dynamic=true;
     }else{
         Vars.Dynamic=false;
     }

     SharedPreferences prefs8 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference9 = prefs8.getBoolean("il", false);
     if (CheckboxPreference9){
         Vars.Israeli=true;
     }else{
         Vars.Israeli=false;
     }
     SharedPreferences prefs81 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference91 = prefs81.getBoolean("jer", false);
     if (CheckboxPreference91){
         Vars.Jerusalem=true;
     }else{
         Vars.Jerusalem=false;
     }       

     SharedPreferences prefs51 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference5 = prefs51.getBoolean("turn", false);
     if (CheckboxPreference5){
         Vars.noRotat=true;
     }else{
         Vars.noRotat=false;
     }

     SharedPreferences prefs9 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     IntPreference10 = prefs9.getString("PrefBear", "0");
     Vars.bearing=Integer.valueOf(IntPreference10);     

     SharedPreferences prefs4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference4 = prefs4.getString("cities", "");
     String fileName="prefsLonLat";
     SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
     Vars.lat = Double.valueOf(prefs1.getString("lat", "40.65"));
     Vars.lon = Double.valueOf(prefs1.getString("lon", "-73.94"));

     if (CheckboxPreference4!=""){
         if (Vars.lat!=40.6501038&&Vars.lon!=-73.94){
             Vars.City=CheckboxPreference4.trim();               
         }else{
             Vars.City="New York, USA";
         }

     }else{//Bad string
         Vars.City="New York, USA";
     }

     SharedPreferences prefs10 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference10 = prefs10.getBoolean("gp", true);
     if (CheckboxPreference10){
         Vars.GP=true;
     }else{
         Vars.GP=false;
     }

     SharedPreferences prefs11 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     CheckboxPreference11 = prefs11.getBoolean("hsys", false);
     if (CheckboxPreference11){
         Vars.HSys=true;
     }else{
         Vars.HSys=false;
     }
}
```

I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity.setPref(MainActivity.java:325)
at com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:499)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: Line 325 is
 boolean bool=true;

Comment: That seems unlikely based on `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity.setPref(MainActivity.java:325)`

Comment: Also, you don't have to create so many `SharedPreferences` objects.  You create it once then reference it as you need it throughout the method.

Comment: Sorry, it is if (VarsNusach.Titl1.contains("lite");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the line that is failing and the fact that you reference `VarsN` above, `Titl1` is null.